# Relocated Moov atom doesnt let chrome play video but firefox can play

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, fastapi

This code is for streaming to an HTML5 video tag and it works fine on firefox but not chrome for certain files.

On Github there is an issue related to this code where the moov atom of the mp4 file is relocated and firefox is able to handle it while chrome isnt able to handle it and thus doesnt stream the video. (Issue: https://github.com/stribny/fastapi-video/issues/1)

Is there any fix to that other than re-encoding or using qt-faststart (basically i want a solution that involves no modification to video file).

The version of this code but for JavaScript works fine on all browsers though.

````py
from pathlib import Path
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Request, Response
from fastapi import Header
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates


app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024*1024
video_path = Path("video.mp4")


@app.get("/")
async def read_root(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", context={"request": request})


@app.get("/video")
async def video_endpoint(range: str = Header(None)):
    start, end = range.replace("bytes=", "").split("-")
    start = int(start)
    end = int(end) if end else start + CHUNK_SIZE
    with open(video_path, "rb") as video:
        video.seek(start)
        data = video.read(end - start)
        filesize = str(video_path.stat().st_size)
        headers = {
            'Content-Range': f'bytes {str(start)}-{str(end)}/{filesize}',
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'
        }
        return Response(data, status_code=206, headers=headers, media_type="video/mp4")```
````

Comment: _"Relocated Moov atom"_ doesn't mean anything. In an MP4 the MOOV either at front or back of file, where else could it relocate to? Or maybe... **(1)** Explain how you "relocate" then we might be able to help fix it. **(2)** Your code is not looking like the expected code for _"This code is for streaming to an HTML5 video tag"_. Does it simply return a result for a video tag code (that is not shown above)?...

Comment: **(3)** Your Github links is about FFmpeg, but **did you also use FFmpeg** (to cut video) to get this problem? Does relocated mean MOOV is now at back of file (because that shown FFmpeg command did not set `-movflags +faststart` anywhere)... If yes then you'll have to read the file into a temporary buffer, edit the buffer (relocate MOOV to front, edit the frame bytes location details inside MOOV atom) then feed modified bytes to your video tag.